# Javascript Switch not working, I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Javascript - switch statements</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var car="ford";

        switch(car){
            case "ferrari";
                document.write("Italian Stalion hey?");
                break;
            case "porsche";
                document.write("German Precision, I like that!");
                break;
            case "dodge";
                document.write("American cars can't corner properly");
                break;

            default:
                document.write("I don't know that car"); 
            //no need for a break because this is the end, its going to end anyways that would be redundant
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't see anything wrong with this. Why is nothing returning regardless of whether or not I change the variable to porsche, or ford. the default class fuckd this up???

Comment: I am not even going to edit this question. lol

Comment: Replace case "porsche"; with  case "porsche":

Comment: In your program have no js reference..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of case statements, use a colon (:) not a semicolon (;). Then your code should be as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript - switch statements</title>
    <script>
        var car = "ford";

        switch (car){
            case "ferrari":
                document.write("Italian Stalion hey?");
                break;
            case "porsche":
                document.write("German Precision, I like that!");
                break;
            case "dodge":
                document.write("American cars can't corner properly");
                break;
            default:
                document.write("I don't know that car");
                break;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it must've been something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace case "statement";   with  case "statement":

You are just immediately terminating case statements with semicolon.

**[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/muvsqbht/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title> Javascript - switch statements</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var car="ford";
switch(car){
   case "ferrari": //This line has changed
       document.write("Italian Stalion hey?");
       break;
   case "porsche": //This line has changed
       document.write("German Precision, I like that!");
       break;
   case "dodge": //This line has changed
       document.write("American cars can't corner properly");
       break;
   default:
       document.write("I don't know that car");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```